# Open CSV file in excel from R script

Tags: r

I have generated a csv file in R and would like my script to open this file in excel so that someone with no knowledge of R can modify the data.  (Ideally when I run the script excel opens and loads this file).  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cmd` command to open an excel file is `open excel file.xlsx`.
In `R` you can run the command line using `system`. So putting these together:

```
excel_file_with_path <- "C:/Users/myusername/Documents/file.xlsx"
command <- paste("open excel", excel_file_with_path)
system(command)
```

Comment: Just a warning that this will need some adaptation to use on other OSes

Comment: This answer is for Windows, but I think it will work on unix/linux systems too if they have Excel installed, although cannot check right now. If not, a slight variation should work (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127297). Of course your path will have a different structure though.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer does not work for me, although not sure why (Windows OS), and I keep having to search for this answer again and again- so here is the answer that works for future reference.

```
shell.exec(here::here("filename.csv"))
```

This should open any file with the default program.
credit: answer lifted directly from Uwe Ligges [outside of SO](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/227427.html)

(note: my use of the `here::here()` function is just an easy way to create a complete filepath, referenced to your RStudio project directory)